# oop call parent function from child class

Tags: javascript

i know this question ask many time before but still i couldn't get my head around it. i'm using javascrit oop and i need to call the parent class function `this.returnResult` from the child class function `this.fullArr`.

```
function parantCls(){ 
    this.sCus = [];
    this.aCus = [];
    this.response;


    this.returnResult = function(msg){
        this.response = {
            result : msg
        };

        return this;
    }
}

function resonse(){
    parantCls.apply(this, arguments);

    this.fullArr = function(){
        // call parent function
        parantCls.prototype.returnResult(this,'setting customField should be array not ' + typeof this.sCus);
        return this.response;
    } 
}

resonse.prototype = new parantCls();
```

Why `parantCls.prototype.returnResult(this,'setting customField should be array not ' + typeof this.sCus);`  is not working. im also used `call and apply` like this

`parantCls.prototype.returnResult.call(this,'setting customField should be array not ' + typeof this.sCus);`

but still don't work. what is the problem

Comment: Depending on how you're calling `fullArr`, your code at the end (`parantCls.prototype.returnResult.call(this,...`) should have worked (although it's unnecessarily complex as you can just use `this.returnResponse` as gzc points out).

Comment: Consequently: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inherit correctly using prototype chain.

This should work

```
this.returnResult('setting customField should be array not ' + typeof this.sCus)
```

By the way, your inheritance looks wrong. use this format.

```
var Subclass = function() {
    Superclass.call(this);
};

Subclass.prototype = Object.create(Superclass.prototype);
Subclass.prototype.constructor = Subclass;

Subclass.prototype.someMethod = function (value) {
    this.x = value;
};
```

Comment: *"By the way, your inheritance looks wrong."* It's not *wrong*, since they aren't using any prototype functions. But yes, it's better to set it up completely. Note: You're missing out important `var`s above, and may want to mention ES2015 syntax. (And missing a `;` at the end.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are very careful. :-)